# How to cache InActive status of app

Tags: android

I am going on with check of my app whether it is active or not.

What i need if i touch any where in device screen it should be in active mode,if there is no any intraction with device for few sec it should show inactive.

Tried with:

```
OnPause()

OnResume()
```

`onUserInteraction()` --> this method will be called when ever i touch the app

If it is not in use that status should be taken,how can i take that status without using OnPause().Is there any other go is there please help me friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what i tried myself and got the solution by the following:

1.)By using **TimerTask** (used TimerTask in Application it's runs for ever 5 min there i set the boolean status)

2.)On BaseActivity of app i had used **onUserInteraction()** there i set boolean status true.

3.)finally i used the boolean condtion in service where the user is acive or not **onUserInteraction()** accordingly start or stop service.

Hopes this help you.